# Pause Video when Modal Popup - HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello i want to pause the video when the modal popup how can I do that ? here is the code

here is the modal when popup - i change it to jumbotron because im more comfortable with it.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div class="text-center col-md-8" style="margin-left: 250px;">

         <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1><u>THIS IS AN ANNOUNCEMENT</u></h1>
          <h1>Please read the announcement</h1>
          <h3>You are a safe passenger</h3>
          <h1><?php echo $row['id']; ?> <?php echo $row['additional_info']; ?></h1>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">TAPOS NA!</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and here is the video src

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" src="../inflightapp/storage/app/public/movie_videos/<?php echo ''.$row2['movie_video'].''; ?>" id="noads" width="1px" controls controlsList="nodownload">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to the video:

```
<video id="myVideo" ...
```

You can pause the video with JavaScript. Call the `pauseVid();` function when modal pops up.

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function pauseVid() { 
  vid.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: can you please edit my code on how is it done ? thanks mate